# php вывод текста

Tags: php

Возможно ли приблизительно так, вывести текст:

```
$result .= if($r = 0) 'It will be'.else 'Is this'.'something here..';
```

То есть выполнить проверку не отдельно, как так:

```
$text = $r = 0 ? 'It will be' : 'Is this';

$result .= $text.'something here..';
```

А сразу же в тексте, и в зависимости от результата, сложить текст.

Comment: `echo ($r == 0 ? 'It will be' : 'Is this') . ' something here..';`

Comment: @Эдуард я думаю что человеку нужно не echo, а как показано в примере $result **.=** , тут я сам не знаю